# Installation of Ubuntu 20.04.2 server fails with CasperMD5CheckMismatches

Tags: system-installation, md5sum

Trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.2 server fails during the installation process. In the log I found:

> ```
> CasperMD5CheckMismatches:
> ./pool/main/l/linux-hwe-5.8/linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-41-generic_5.8.0-41.46~20.04.1_amd6.deb
> ```

I have verified the iso-file:

```
d1f2bf834bbe9bb43faf16f9be992a6f3935e65be0edece1dee2aa6eb1767423 *ubuntu-20.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso
```

Installation of the desktop version 20.04.2 on the same machine works.

Any ideas what to do?

[image]